# Image validation with multiple dimensions not working

Tags: php, laravel

so Im using Laravel 5.6 and have this validation rule like this:

```
$request->validate([
    'image-x' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png|max:4096|dimensions:
                                    max_width=2000,
                                    max_height=2000,
                                    min_width=512,
                                    min_height=512,
                                    ratio=1/1'
]);
```

I would like to have pictures that are bigger than 512x512px, smaller than 2000x2000px, and with aspect ratio 1:1. I've been playing with this for a good hour now (different solutions from google), but anytime I insert an image with dimensions like 3840x1080px or so, it passes the validation. Does anybody have experience with setting multiple **dimensions** values? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be work try this:

```
$request->validate([
'image-x' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png|max:4096|'.Rule::dimensions()->minWidth(512)->minHeight(512)->maxWidth(2000)->maxHeight(2000)->ratio(1/1)]);
```

Comment: I dont exactly understand why this would be different from my solution, but it worked, thanks!